# How to start a v-for loop at a specific index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to start a `v-for` loop at a specific index.

example: A array given `array = [a,b,c,d,e,f];`

I want use `v-for` loop which will start looping from 3rd element. Thank you :)

Comment: Add two - `index + 2`?

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use standard slice method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      'aaa',
      'bbb',
      'ccc',
      'ddd',
      'eee',
      'fff'
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in items.slice(2)">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

PS: Or v-for with v-if:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      'aaa',
      'bbb',
      'ccc',
      'ddd',
      'eee',
      'fff'
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in items" v-if="index >= 2">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or with custom function:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      'aaa',
      'bbb',
      'ccc',
      'ddd',
      'eee',
      'fff'
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    startFrom (arr, idx) {
      return arr.slice(idx)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in startFrom(items, 2)">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `[vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for]`
The 'undefined' variable inside 'v-for' directive should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the filter method you will have to loop through the array in the computed value as well as in the display. Given that you know your starting element in the array you would be better of using **slice** either in your 

`<div v-for="(item , index) in array.slice(1,array.length)">`

or if you still want to use a computed value
```

```
computed:{
  getArray(){
    return this.array.slice(1,this.array.length)
  }
}
```

I would recommend using the computed value.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use **computed** values [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```
    <template>
      <div class="message">
   
   <div v-for="(item , index) in getArray">
   

    <span>{{item}}</span>

</div>
      
</div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    
      export default {
        name: 'message',
         data () {
           return{
               array:['a','b','c','d','e']
             }
        },
        methods:{
            
        },
        computed:{
            getArray(){
                    const arr = this.array.filter((item , index)=>{
                             return index > 1; //will return the array from the second value
                      })
                  return arr;
            }
        }
      }
    
    </script>
    
    <style>
    
    
    </style>
```

Comment: it should be `<div v-for="(item , index) in getArray">`

Comment: Please avoid [code-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)